# RaptureXML could not load data from user path

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xml-parsing

I'm new to iOS development. I've found [RaptureXML](https://github.com/ZaBlanc/RaptureXML) and it works quiet well but I could not load data which I stored in my user directory. Having a "data.xml" within my application directory works fine, I could load it with `[RXMLElement elementFromXMLFile:@"data.xml"];`. But now I have downloaded a file from Internet and stored it in my user directory using these lines:

```
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [paths objectAtIndex:0],@"data.xml"];
```

The computed file path is

> "/Users/*myname*/Library/Application Support/iPhone
>   Simulator/6.0/Applications/*myapplicationguid*/Documents/data.xml"

.

The file exists, I've checked with `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filename];`. I've also opened it manually and placed the value from the example XML File from RaptureXML there, so it could not be any mismatches within the XML or else....

But when I use `[RXMLElement elementFromXMLFile:filename]` it does not return anything... Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've now made a workaround: As direct access does not work, I'm first loading the data using standard functions and then transfer the NSData to RaptureXML like this:

```
 NSError *error;
    NSString* contents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filename
                                                   encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                      error:&error];
    NSData* xmlData = [contents dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    RXMLElement *rss = [RXMLElement elementFromXMLData:xmlData];
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to use *initFromXMLFilePath:* method.

```
 RXMLElement *rss = [[RXMLElement alloc]initFromXMLFilePath: filePath];
```